# Extracting Dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a database which has information about clinics.

Each clinic has an opening date(say, 2014-05-23 00:00:00) and a field called MIO(monthsInOperation), which basically is the number of months the clinic has operated.

For each clinic I need the Calendar Month and Year in the format (say, July-13) based on the current month of operation(MIO), which in the database can be 0,1,2,....and so on.

I know I need to use `DATEADD()` or `DATEPART()` or `DATEDIFF()` function. But I am unable to get the desired result.

**The answer for the last Clinic should be Feb-2012**

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried that didn't work?  Also, since you have the exact date you need, there's no need for functions like `DATEADD()` OR `DATEDIFF()`.

Comment: @STLDeveloper I have the opening date and the MonthsInOperation field, I need to know the Calendar Month and Year for the corresponding MonthInOperation. For example if opening date is (2013-05-23 00:00:00) and the MIO is 13, the what is the value of calendar month and year when the MIO is 0,1,2,3 and so on. I hope I am clear?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Are you clear with above explanation?

Comment: @user3681350 - Unfortunately, I'm not following you.  In the example above, if the MIO value is 12, what would you expect the answer to be?

Comment: @STLDeveloper If MIO is 12: Then answer will be May-14

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if I'm misunderstanding your question, but is there a reason you can't just do something like this?

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, MonthsInOperation, OpenDate) FROM Clinics
```

That won't give you just a month and year, but there's no such type in SQL anyway. You can handle the resulting `DATE` or `DATETIME` on your client's code and `ToString` it to be in the format (`MM-yyyy` or what have you) that you want it in. You could also separate them out using the [`MONTH(DATE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) and [`YEAR(DATE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) functions, although I wouldn't bother, personally. It seems like more a UI matter that you want only to see the month and year.

```
SELECT MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, MonthsInOperation, OpenDate)), YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, MonthsInOperation, OpenDate))
```

It sounds like that will output the two columns you need to work with: the month and year.

However,

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(month, MonthsInOperation, OpenDate)) + "-" + YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, MonthsInOperation, OpenDate)))
```

should give exactly what you want, again, if I'm understanding you properly.

Comment: @user3681350 not really more than I was before. Is your issue with this solution simply the formatting? This would return the values you gave as examples for each case. If your concern is formatting, that's a different matter.

Comment: I suppose, could you try running this select along with your other one and tell me where the *values* are wrong. Note, values, not formats.

Comment: I can format it on my own, that is not an issue, I am just looking for the "month and year" corresponding to the opening date and the value of monthsinoperation. For example in the above picture clinic#8 opened on March-2011, so based on MIO(which is 11), the month and year will be Feb-2012(the answer which i need).

Comment: Actually my bad, the solution you wrote above works. It will give me the desired result and after that it is just a matter of formatting.

Comment: @user3681350 I thought that might be the case. No problem. I'm glad I could be of assistance. Is that it, then? Or is there another facet to your question we can help with?

Comment: @user3681350 If this answered your questions completely I would appreciate if you'd accept my answer to help people in the future and remove this question from the unanswered queue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank You Matthew, Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of the months when each clinic is open, you can do that.  The first thing you need is a list of numbers, the rest is pretty easy.

```
with n as (
      select 0 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < 50
     )
select c.*, year(dateadd(month, n.n, c.opening_date)),
       month(dateadd(month, n.n, c.opening_date))
from clinics c join
     n
     on n.n <= c.mio;
```

I've chosen to format the year and month as two separate numeric columns.  You can use `datename()` or `convert()` to get a specific format.

EDIT:

If you just want the latest month, that is much simpler:

```
select c.*, year(dateadd(month, c.mio, c.opening_date)),
       month(dateadd(month, c.mio, c.opening_date))
from clinics c;
```

Comment: It is not giving the correct answer, I have edited my post and included the sample data. Do not worry about the values, it includes the forecast also, so the MIO you see above is not in accordance to the actual opening date.

Comment: How is this not producing the correct answer?  Here is a SQL fiddle producing the list of dates:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20253.